# Como mostrar o ocultar botón en componente genérico en Angular?

Tags: angular

Sabiendo que estoy utilizando un componente genérico que se replica en varias paginas , mi pregunta es como puedo hacer para que el botón se muestre en cierta pagina y en la otra se oculte o se muestre otro texto , bueno estoy utilizando ng-témplate y me puse a buscar información pero no hay mucha ya que hay otras formas que no entiendo , aqui mi codigo :

-

```
<div *ngIf="path == '/home' ;else otra"> 
    <button > home </button> 
</div>

<ng-template #otra>  
      <button "> otra pagina </button> 
</ng-template>



el "path" lo tengo como public path: string = '';
```

No se si esta bien de esta forma, en algunas paginas me dicen que no funciona el ngIf con el ng-témplate , pero bueno les agradezco cualquier información.